# Gloss JSON: init model from string

Tags: json, swift, frameworks

I'm having trouble performing a very simple task in [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss): constructing a model instance from a string.

Gloss defines the `typealias JSON`:

```
public typealias JSON = [String : Any]
```

and expects an instance of `JSON` when deserializing JSON using its `Decodable` protocol:

```
struct MyModel: Decodable {
    let item1: String?
    let item2: String?
    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.item1 = "item1" <~~ json
        self.item2 = "item2" <~~ json
    }
}
```

The [Gloss documentation](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss/blob/develop/README.md#initializing-model-objects-and-arrays) explains how to initialize a model object from an array of type `[String : Any]` (aka `JSON`) but it does not mention how a model object can be initialized from a JSON-string.

I found the following solution, but there must be a simpler/cleaner solution:

```
// Assume the following is in a function
let jsonString = "{\"item1\":\"some value\", \"item2\":\"another value\"}"
guard let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
    else { return nil }
guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    else { return nil }
guard let json = jsonData as? JSON
    else { return nil }
return MyModel(json: json)
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is this the only way to make Gloss decode a JSON-string?

Comment: @EricAya I'm encoding some data in a QR code. I thought it'd be a good solution to use JSON as the data will be key-value pairs (and possible nested objects). It might very well be that I'm heading down a wrong path though, I'm open to suggestions :)

Comment: @EricAya I see. In this case I'm using [this framework](https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift) for scanning the QR codes. I receive the result as a [QRCodeReaderResult](https://github.com/yannickl/QRCodeReader.swift/blob/master/Sources/QRCodeReaderResult.swift), which means the returned data is represented as a string.

Comment: Okay, thank you :).